# shortcut for calling a method

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

I have a dll that contains a class with a method called Test.
Currently I call it this way:

```
Mydll.MyClass.Test()
```

I can't use
`Using Mydll` and call `MyClass.Test()` because I have a class with the same name even in the source I'm using.
There is a faster way to call the `Test()` method without necessarily having to write `Mydll.MyClass.Test()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All function calls need a type, but you can make a type alias for `Mydll.MyClass`.

IIRC, this was the syntax:

```
//Alias definition
using SomeClass = Mydll.MyClass;
//Later calling
SomeClass.Test();
```

Comment: "*All function calls need a type*" -- not *strictly* true, with `using static`

Comment: @canton7 the static function `Test()` would beg to differ :) | It is more like some functions need a instance of some types.

Comment: @canton7 Fixed it to the "would beg to differ" I intended.

Comment: I don't follow. [This is valid](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+A7AhgWxgZwAcswYACAMQggFgAoAb3rJbIAEBmdgRiXYCYyAFQAWASwwBzZqyZ1WClpx582KYQQAuACgCUZBmQC+rGSyP0LdetjxES5APKaRMKPTkK2ABhWVqAHSiEpIA3GbsXGyCAMIRnopKUeoAsnoRCgmJCkJaeuHy2VYKVkZAA=)

Comment: @canton7 That one get's it's type from the using directive. .NET is strongly typed. You might avoid *writing* (most of) the type, you can bet every byte in your code the compiler actually uses the fully types.

Comment: Of course. But strictly speaking the function call to `Test()` in my example *does not* need you to specify a type, because we've got that `using static` directive. The compiler figures out the type for you. Hence my comment.